# TinyMCE retain pre-defined html structure

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm looking for a way for TinyMCE to enforce a predefined HTML structure when editing.

For example, say I have the structure below. I want a user to be able to add content between the sections, but not remove the section headers themselves.

I currently do this by dynamically opening a TinyMCE instance when I click on each section, But I'd rather have the overall content loaded into a single editor, that will provide a better experience for the user.

1. Section 1

   edit text here
2. Section 2

   edit text here
3. Section 3

   edit text here

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE has a plugin called `noneditable` that should allow you to do this:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/noneditable/

Here is some example HTML that leverages this plugin:

```
    <table style="width: 60%;" border="1">
        <caption class="mceNonEditable">Ephox Sales Analysis</caption> 
        <tbody> 
            <tr class="mceNonEditable"> 
                <th style="width: 40%;">&nbsp;</th> 
                <th style="width: 15%;">Q1</th> 
                <th style="width: 15%;">Q2</th> 
                <th style="width: 15%;">Q3</th> 
                <th style="width: 15%;">Q4</th> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td class="mceNonEditable">East Region</td> 
                <td>100</td> <td>110</td> <td>115</td> <td>130</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td class="mceNonEditable">Central Region</td> 
                <td>100</td> <td>110</td> <td>115</td> <td>130</td> 
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td class="mceNonEditable">West Region</td> 
                <td>100</td> <td>110</td> <td>115</td> <td>130</td> 
            </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table>
```

Any tag that contains that class (and all of its children) will be non-editable.

Comment: I overlooked that plugin. I'll take a look at it to see if it can truly do what I need. Thanks.